# How can I secure a SQL Server connection using certificate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Windows app is opening a database connection to SQL Server sitting remotely using a `SqlConnection` object without any proper security measure.

I would like to secure the database connection using a certificate. I read something about adding the certificate on SQL Server, and on my Windows application. But I am confused how to do it as well as not sure how effective it would be.

Any ideas or helpful link to article?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate (or related)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998377/authenticating-sql-connection-using-certificates-in-net

Comment: Is the goal to use certificates for authentication, or is it about securing the channel similarly to how HTTP connections can be secured with SSL?

Comment: It would help if you linked and shared some details about what you have researched.

Comment: @Sean U -  iam looking for first type - certificates for authentication

Comment: @DRastislav In that case, see the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2998831/516797) to the question JasonHeine mentioned.  It's possible to configure SQL Server to use SSL to secure the channel, but authentication still needs to be done using Windows or SQL auth.